# Xcode 11.5 Assistant editor show any file

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode11.5

I want to be able to open any file in the assistant editor. Right now it is forcing me to open "counterparts", "test classes" and other stuff that i dont need.
I need two different classes to look at.

In previous xcodes it was possible
Where is this option in Xcode 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either `alt + click` in the file navigator to open in a new editor, or click this icon:

[image]

(pro tip: hold `alt` to toggle new editor position [on right | below])

Also, `alt + click` on a file while more than one editors are open will open the file in the *non* focused one.

Finally, `ctrl + alt + cmd + click` on a symbol will open that symbol in a new editor (or to the secondary if you got more than one).

Bonus: `alt + enter` on a quick open result (`cmd + shift + O`) will save you the trip to the file navigator.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the assitant editor, simply click on the "+" icon in the top right

[image]

"Add editor on right"